# incorrect encoding of rsyslog output

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, syslog

I'm running a rsyslog service in a docker container.

Its configuration(**rsyslog.conf**) looks like below,

> module(load="imuxsock")    # local system logging support (e.g. via
> logger command)
>
> module(load="imudp")       # UDP listener support module(load="imtcp")
>
> module(load="mmutf8fix")
>
> action(type="mmutf8fix")
>
> LOCAL1.*                                                  action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/my.log")

The client program is Java program that is using logback to write the log to both local file and remote rsyslog service.

The local log file looks like for non-ascii characters, whose encoding is UTF-8.

However the output file of rsyslog is **NOT** UTF-8. Of course the non-ascii characters can not be shown properly.

> ➜  rsyslog git:(master) ✗ file /volume/disk/logs/svt/my.log
>
> /volume/disk/logs/svt/my.log: ASCII text, with very long lines

I'm wondering how to configure rsyslog to write output as UTF-8, there is no obvious solution after searching Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem is that the default locale of the container is not **UTF-8**. I'm using **alpine** linux as the OS of rsyslog container. Finally adding below environment declarations in `Dockerfile` to fix the encoding issue.

```
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
```